# How to change "way" of searching in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nautilus

So I recently upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04 and whilst my experience has been good one thing kinda bugs me when using the file browser (Nautilus).

When I'm in a directory and I wish to search in this directory Nautilus starts searching in my entire computer instead of just snapping to the first file/folder starting with the letter I typed.

So the behaviour I'm looking for is basically this. Imagine I have a directory with 3 folders in it called foo, bar and baz. Then when I click the letter 'B' I simply want nautilus to snap to bar, instead of bringing up this search bar as it does now.

Is this possible?